# BackboneForms different key than display possible?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-forms

I have a very simple form:

```
var UserForm = Backbone.Form.extend({
    template: _.template($('#formTemplate').html()),

    schema: {
        venue:      { validators: ['required'] },
    },
    model: this.model
});
```

This create a label with name `Venue` and puts a textfield beside it. But what if I want to name the label `VenueName` and keep the key it assigns to model `venue`. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#main-attributes) yes, this is very easy:

```
var UserForm = Backbone.Form.extend({
    template: _.template($('#formTemplate').html()),

    schema: {
        venue: {
            validators: ['required'],
            title: 'Venue Name'
        },
    },
    model: this.model
});
```